# Use another form datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have one form like main form, where are mounted other forms in c#. But I can't access the datatable of mounted other forms from the main form and other forms.

So I'm interested to "share" a datatable from the mounted form, which I can use from others forms. Any idea how to do this?!

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn about [Accessibility Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and basic [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) ([here's more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx)). And make sure you understand, at the very least, the [fundamentals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Fundamental_features_and_concepts). By making some object (for example a datatable) public by exposing it via a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) (or `GetFoo()` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) you can access it. You need to realize a [form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) is just another [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx).

However, you also need to consider [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and/or [Separation of presentation and content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content); a Form might not be (and usually **is** not) the correct "object" to share these kinds of things. All a form should be concerned about it presenting the user an interface and display some data. You might want to consider another object holding the datatable and/or more data-logic and pass that object into Form_A and Form_B instead of having Form_A access Form_B's public properties.

Comment: And, in general, a Form should not _own_ a Table. That's the job of a DAL or Repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new to the programming but I know how Accessibility Levels and how to use the property. The problem is where i want to use a data table (ex. dt) from another form, first i create the object(ex. objForm) of that form, then when I try to use the data table with object (ex. objForm.dt) the value of datatable is null.